# Generate XML from schema using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd

Can we generate 'sample xml files' from a given schema using JavaScript only? Is there any library for doing this?

Comment: I don't know any dedicated library but you can always use XSLT transformation in your JS code to create XML from any XML Schema.

Comment: Actually I need to generate some blank xmls from a given schema on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to create a XMLDocument Object in Internate Explorer,the creation of XMLDocument Object is automatically by the brower when received a xml string.
But in FireFox,new XMLDocument is allowed.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

If its just your quick requirement to generate some sample XMLs .. rather than practicing Javascript coding 
go for Altova XMLSpy :) (a trial version of 30 days is available)

 You would have options like

1. Generate non-mandatory attributes/elements.
2. Fill elements with dummy data .. example: if you declare an element with `maxLength = 10` it will write resulting xml as `<node>aaaaaaaaaa</node>`
3. Generate first choice of mandatory choice? 

    Etc etc ......

Well I am searching a way to generate XML from XSD using code too .. :|